# Private Key generation in Hyperledger Fabric in Centeralized

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Hyperledger Fabric when identity is issued the certificate and Key is shared by the admin unlike in multichain where the user receives the key as response and it is not shared with anyone not even admin.

**Is it possible in some way in Fabric?** *If not then Hyperledger is not decentralized it is only distributed.*

Comment: With fabric-ca, in my opinion, we don't have any official way to do it.   
In my real case, I must rewrite this part of Hyperledger and instead of generate both signed cert and key, I asked end user create his key/csr by himself. When he want to issue certificate, he must send his csr to us and we will return him his cert :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. An admin registers a new user by the certificate authority and gets a "secret" back.
This secret is then used by the client to enroll directly by the certificate authority and get his own key/certs, with nobody in between.